# Autolayout in xCode does not act as expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, layout

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

First, I did pack these 25 blocks in 5 horizontal stacks and then packed them into one big vertical stack.

When adding alignment constraints Xcode does not change the distance between the blocks and instead makes one block in each row bigger than the rest.

Any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: StackViews ignore your constraints depending on distribution and alignment paramters. Explain what you want to get in result

Comment: i want all blocks to be same sized and alignt to the top, left and right.

Comment: try set horizontal UIStackView's Alignment = top and playing with leading and trailing constraints for each view

Answer (score 0):

create the first one like this 
[image]

then copy paste it inside the main outer stack
[image]

see demo here [stack](https://github.com/ShKhan9/stack)